# error NETSDK1097 requesting a RuntimeIdentifier when moving from .Net Core 3 to .Net 5

Tags: .net-core

I am building single file executables for both MacOS (osx-x64) and Windows (win-x64).

My command line is:

> dotnet publish --nologo -r osx-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true

When moving to .Net 5, I am now getting this error:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(142,5):
> error NETSDK1097: It is not supported to publish an application to a
> single-file without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier. You must either
> specify a RuntimeIdentifier or set PublishSingleFile to false.

So I decided to add the RuntimeIdentifier section:

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>osx-x64;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

It turns out that this needs to be in every sub-project.. a bit annoying but ok.

But now, it doesn't work:

> Applications published to a single-file are required to use the application host. You must either set PublishSingleFile to false or set UseAppHost to true.

Additionally, if I add all on the command line:

> dotnet publish --nologo -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:UseAppHost=true /p:RuntimeIdentifier=osx-x64 -r osx-x64

I get the same error. It looks like the config on the dotnet command line gets ignored.

Adding the runtime identifier to all the project files, yields:

> error MSB6006: "dotnet" exited with code 1.

which doesn't really say anything.

My question is:

has the behavior changed with .NET 5 (I can't find anything on the topic), or is the preview that is broken?